# Access Fields in a C# CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have used EF6 to access a DB and retrieve a DbSet entity (`DbSet<Asset> Assets`) from a table called `Asset`.

The rows of the table are stored in a CollectionViewSource (`CollectionViewSource x:Key="assetViewSource"`) that provides the `DataContext` for a WPF Xaml GUI.

The fields of the GUI represent the columns of the table and they are bound to the fields in the assetViewSource like so:

```
Text="{Binding Path=AssetCategory, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"
```

It all works and the user can interact with the database through the GUI.

Can anyone tell me how I can access the data in the fields in the `assetViewSource` collection from the code behind after they have been updated from the GUI but before the changes are Saved to the RMS_DB database?

I want to be able to do something in the Code behind like the following:

```
codebehindField = assetViewSource.Asset.AssetCategory.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the information I needed to answer this question in the "Getting and setting the current or original value of an individual property" section of the MSDN document titled "Entity Framework Working with Property Values" at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592677(v=vs.113).aspx
I'll post the code I wrote to solve my problem below in case someone else finds it useful....

```
    // Update "DateRecordLastUpdated" in GUI because changes have been made to the Process' fields.
    // Get the entity's primary key from the GUI and use it to Find the corresponding entity in the CollectionView.
    int OrgUnitID = int.Parse(viewAsset_assetOrgUnitIDTextBox.Text);
    int AssetClassID = int.Parse(viewAsset_assetAssetClassIDTextBox.Text);
    int AssetID = int.Parse(viewAsset_assetIDTextBox.Text);
    var selectedEntity = rmsDb.Assets.Find(OrgUnitID, AssetClassID, AssetID);       // Primary key components must be in sequence.
    rmsDb.Entry(selectedEntity).Property(u => u.DateRecordLastUpdated).CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(viewAsset_dateRecordLastUpdated, TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateTarget();           //Trigger GUI binding refresh
    rmsDb.SaveChanges();
```

Many thanks to those commenting on my earlier post.